# transforming an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, format

I'm trying to transform an array of objects with javascript. Below is an example of the raw data and what the formatted array should look like. I've tried accomplishing this with some loops and if,else statements but couldn't figure it out. There must be a more efficient way of accomplishing a task like this with javascript? I'm new working with javascript so any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

I've tried this...

```
// get formatted reports array
        $scope.reports = [];
        var num = 1;
        // console.log("reports: ", $scope.reports_data);
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.reports_data.length; i++) {
            var row = {
                "reviewer_1" : "",
                "reviewer_2" : "",
                "reviewer_3" : "",
                "created_at" : ""
            };
            if(num == $scope.reports_data[i].report_id) {
                row.created_at = $scope.reports_data[i].created_at;
                if($scope.reports_data[i].stage == 1 ) {
                    row.reviewer_1 = $scope.reports_data[i].full_name;
                } else if($scope.reports_data[i].stage == 2) {
                    row.reviewer_2 = $scope.reports_data[i].full_name;
                } else {
                    row.reviewer_3 = $scope.reports_data[i].full_name;
                }
            }
            $scope.reports.push(row);
            num += 1;
        }
```

Before:

```
    var raw_arr = [
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Dick",
        "report_id" : 1,
        "stage" : 1
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Tom",
        "report_id" : 1,
        "stage" : 2
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Harry",
        "report_id" : 1,
        "stage" : 3
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"John",
        "report_id" : 2,
        "stage" : 1
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Mike",
        "report_id" : 2,
        "stage" : 2
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Charles",
        "report_id" : 2,
        "stage" : 3
    }
];
```

After:

```
 var formatted_arr = [
        {
            "created_at": "2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
            "report_id": 1,
            "reviewer_1": "Dick",
            "reviewer_2": "Tom",
            "reviewer_3": "Harry",
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
            "report_id": 2,
            "reviewer_1": "John",
            "reviewer_2": "Mike",
            "reviewer_3": "Charles",
        }
    ];
```

Comment: So you want to group the original array by `report_id` and add each person to the new object? *"I've tried accomplishing this with some loops and if,else statements but couldn't figure it out."* so where is that code?

Comment: And this isn't "formatting" an array, this is "transforming" an array into a different array

Comment: @Matt Burland that is correct

Comment: @MattBurland, check out the edits.. any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.reduce` is your friend here. Usually I'd suggest reducing to an object using the id as a key, but since your keys are numeric anyway, we can just use them as keys to an array directly:

```js
    var raw_arr = [
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Dick",
        "report_id" : 1,
        "stage" : 1
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Tom",
        "report_id" : 1,
        "stage" : 2
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Harry",
        "report_id" : 1,
        "stage" : 3
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"John",
        "report_id" : 2,
        "stage" : 1
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Mike",
        "report_id" : 2,
        "stage" : 2
    },
    {
        "created_at" :"2016-05-04T16:45:07.000Z",
        "full_name" :"Charles",
        "report_id" : 2,
        "stage" : 3
    }
];

var outputArr = raw_arr.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (!p[c.report_id - 1]) {
        p[c.report_id - 1] = { 
            created_at: c.created_at,
            report_id: c.report_id
        }
    }
    p[c.report_id - 1]["reviewer_" + c.stage] = c.full_name;
    return p;
},[]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(outputArr));
```

The important part is here:

```
var outputArr = raw_arr.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (!p[c.report_id - 1]) {
        p[c.report_id - 1] = { 
            created_at: c.created_at,
            report_id: c.report_id
        }
    }
    p[c.report_id - 1]["reviewer_" + c.stage] = c.full_name;
    return p;
},[]);
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var grouped = lodash.groupBy(raw_array, 'report_id');
lodash.map(grouped, function(collection) {
    var result = collection[0];
    delete result.full_name;
    delete result.stage;
    lodash.map(collection, function(item, i) {
        result['reviewer_' + (i + 1)] = item.full_name;
    });
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... ReferenceError: lodash is not defined

Comment: @MattBurland's answer is better